# Bootstrap Pop-Over not working on first mouseenter event

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
  <div class="pop" style="display: none">
         'Dynamic content here'
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="opinionmap" rel="popover"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>

$('.opinionmap').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).popover({title: 'Current Opinion', trigger: 'hover', html: 'true', content: $(this).siblings('.pop').html(), placement: 'top'});
});
```

But the popover is working only after the second mouseenter event.
I have viewed many related questions but none helped.
Seeking answers!!!

Comment: popover functionality is to take care of mouse enter and leave events, you don't need to do that.

Comment: @slash197 Yes!!! but since i have to bring in a content that is why i am doing this

Comment: it's the wrong way to do it

Comment: @slash197 I Agree. Please guide on the right way!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use only this

```
$('.opinionmap').popover({
    title: 'Current Opinion', 
    trigger: 'hover', 
    html: 'true', 
    content: $('.opinionmap').siblings('.pop').html(),
    placement: 'top'
});
```

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing before posting,,but it does not give any vontent this ways..

Comment: and...since all this HTML is under a loop all there are many .opinionmap. That is why $(this) is needed!!!

Answer (score 0):

Okk..So anyone has the same problem in the future...here is how i have solved it.

```
  $('.opinionmap').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).popover({title: 'Current Opinion', trigger: 'hover', html: 'true', content: $(this).siblings('.pop').html(), placement: 'top'}).popover('show');
    ;
  });
```